# is there a way to index groups of values in c++

Tags: c++, indexing, mingw

I was wondering if there was a way to exclude indexes or get a group of indexes. For example, suppose I have a string. i want to the last 3 characters and put them into a string variable. Is there a way to do this without a for loop or user-defined/external functions?

```
string coolstring = "coolstr";
string CoolStringWithoutTheCool = coolstring[4-6] // trying to grab the last 3 values ("str")
```

Comment: For this specific case `std::string` has [`std::string::substring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). There is no general index range feature in c++. `operator[]` basically always just takes an integer. The question would have been much clearer if you had used an array like `int[10]` to illustrate the scenario. `std::string` distracts from the actual question by having a member function for this exact use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C++` the concept of slicing is usually met by **Iterators**.

Iterators are like pointers to elements, and two iterators, `begin` and `end` define a range.

So, in your case, you would want

```cpp
string CoolStringWithoutTheCool = std::string(coolstring.begin() + 4, coolstring.begin() + 7);
```

There is a special method for strings, called `substr`, which does the same

```cpp
string CoolStringWithoutTheCool = coolstring.substr(4, 3); // You want the length to be 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use substr

```
std::string x = coolstring.substr(4, 2);
```